# GWT: EntityManager NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, jboss, smartgwt

I am using GWT with the SmartGWT library to make an application and I deploy this on a JBoss server. To authenticate my users, I made a JPA Entity and a ManagerBean. However, when I try to use the EntityManager in this ManagerBean, I get a NullPointerException. The EntityManager works in every other class, but not in the AppUser class.

Code from AppUserManagerBean:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
private EntityManager em;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("be.test.server.AppUserManagerBean");

public boolean checkUser(String username,String password){

    logger.info("ENTITY MANAGER: " + em.toString());
    AppUser user = null;
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT OBJECT(a) FROM AppUser a WHERE a.username = :username AND a.password = :password");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
```

Error logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    be.test.server.auth.AppUserManagerBean.checkUser(AppUserManagerBean.java:23)
    be.test.server.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:29)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:130)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:148)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

I am aware this probably isn't enough info, so feel free to ask me for more in the comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How your EntityManager is getting created and initialised with db credentials? is it within xml configuration?

Comment: I have a Persistence.xml file, but the datasource specifications are in standalone.xml in the JBoss folder =)

Comment: Which source line is line 23 in `checkUser`?

Comment: Line 23 is where I use em.toString(), but this also occurred when I tried to use the EntityManager for anything else, like em.createQuery()

Answer (score 2):

make sure AppUserManagerBean is also instantiated by the container and not by yourself.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by 'container'?

Comment: if you instantiate the class by a new Operator like new AppUserManagerBean(), than nothing can be injected into it because the lifecycle of it is not under jboss Server control.

Comment: so with container i mean the jboss server, more specific its cdi subsystem

Comment: So, would that be an XML file I have to edit? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm quite new to JBoss and configuring servers in general.

Comment: Normaly this is configured in the beans.xml file or via annotaions like you do, i see your using spring so this can be different here. Just keep in mind that you can only inject beans into beans with are container managed. Given only this information Iam just guessing if this is really your problem.

Comment: beans.xml has no configurations, I'm afraid.

Comment: an empty beans.xml doesnt mean that the cdi doesnt work, it just indicates that it is configured via annotation. you should check if you instantiate the AppUserManagerBean via new or if you get if from another bean.

Comment: than it cant work, you mentioned its works in other classes maybe you can look how its done there

Comment: I tried it the way of the other classes, with an @EJB annotation, but I get the same error.